# Copying data from a sharepoint site into Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am new to VBA and SharePoint. I have been researching a lot of different forums and help sites, but I still can't find what I am looking for.

I am using Excel 2007  I am trying to copy a Summary tab from different excel documents on a sharePoint site. The excel documents are in different folders and I am prompted for read only or Edit before the workbook opens. There are only 25 or so workbooks that I am trying to pull.

I would ideally like to pull the summary information from the different excel workbooks into one master excel sheet with each summary sheet having its own tab in the master excel document. I think I can write the code for that part it getting the information to the master excel document that I am not sure where to start.  Any help or advice would be great!

Comment: You can probably find the network drive location of each excel document and use normal read methods to open them within Excel via VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at JavaScript and make it to work with all browsers. Look at this library https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js and the related site https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js